# Restore original encoding in Sublime Text 2

Tags: encoding, sublimetext2, iconv

I opened a file and didn't noticed that it was in windows-1251 encoding. It was opened as utf-8 encoded file with incorrect characters. Then I pasted there a bunch of code in utf-8 encoding. After saving (with some error message about falling back to UTF-8) I can't restore file's original content. I reopen new file, cut all pasted code and save it. Nether "reopen with encoding" nor "save with encoding" don't give the correct-encoded file.

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t WINDOWS-1251 file.txt > file_1251.txt
```

Iconv says there's an illegal input sequence.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's still in Windows-1251. Decoding the original file incorrectly as UTF-8 and overwriting wouldn't result in a file that is incorrect UTF-8 and so you wouldn't see the error.

Try

```
iconv -f Windows-1251 -t UTF-8 file.txt > file_UTF8.txt
```

And open the UTF-8 file normally as UTF-8.